Use bitmask with isar database
I have a class in my flutter project that uses a bitmask to store certain flags in an int. Objects of this class are stored in an isar database and I want to query these objects based on the flags.
Therefore I wanted to perform a logical AND operation on the objects int and an int generated in the application to filter. I have no idea how to do this with isar. If its not possible, are there other efficient ways (in terms of performance and storage) to store multiple bools in the database (the number might change with the application developing)
